# Can I play AAC internet radio with wmp.dll in C#?

Tags: c#, aac, wmplib

Is this possible? If yes, can you provide any information on HOW to do this? If no, are there any other possible ways to decode AAC stream in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered Bass library ?

http://www.un4seen.com/

Comment: I tried BASS. With no luck. Even one example program in the Internet done on bass.dll doesn't play AAC.

Comment: Try harder, I have many software that use Bass AND aac installed on my PC right now. Check for the .net samples, there is an internet radio player that works pretty well. Maybe you didn't copy the aac decoder dll in the bin directory ? Please give Bass a second chance.

Comment: Oooh, I need to copy aac decoder too? Sorry, I'll try that. Thanks!